# No output operations registered, so nothing to execute in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am trying to integtrate Spark with Kafka. I am having the kafka consumer have json data. I want to inegrate the kafka consumer with Spark for processing. When I run the below code error is throwing.

```
bin\spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.0 test.py localhost:9092 maktest
```

My test.py is below

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,[topic],{"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    print (lines)
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I got the error below

```
18/12/10 16:41:40 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
18/12/10 16:41:40 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to
18/12/10 16:41:40 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to
<pyspark.streaming.kafka.KafkaTransformedDStream object at 0x000002A6DA9FE6A0>
18/12/10 16:41:40 ERROR StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/maws/Desktop/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    ssc.start()

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.start.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
```

Comment: did you manage to try out the provided solution? If it worked, please accept the answer, provide more feedback or post your own answer to close the solution. Please read stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using a supported [Spark Streaming DStream output operation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams).

For the pyspark API, you should use:

```
pprint()
saveAsTextFiles(prefix, [suffix])
saveAsObjectFiles(prefix, [suffix])
saveAsHadoopFiles(prefix, [suffix])
foreachRDD(func)
```

`print()` can't be used with pyspark, so make sure when you check other Spark Streaming Examples for Scala or Java, you change to `pprint()`